# How do you type hint overriding a built in axios method that returns a promise?

Tags: typescript, apisauce

I've been trying to add a caching layer to apisauce.
I followed a guide on https://techblog.geekyants.com/a-guide-to-react-native-offline-support which gave me the following code:

```
import {create} from 'apisauce';

import cache from '../utility/cache';

const apiClient = create({
  baseURL: 'https://randomuser.me',
});

const get = apiClient.get;

//^ altering the get()
apiClient.get = async (url, params, axiosConfig) => {
  const response = await get(url, params, axiosConfig);

  if (response.ok) {
    await cache.store(url, response.data); //* caching the response
    return response;
  }

  const data = await cache.get(url); //* retrieving the data from the cache
  return data ? {ok: true, data} : response;
};

export default apiClient;
```

This code works perfectly, however it throws errors which I cannot figure out how to resolve.

The specific error that I'm getting is:

> src/api/client.tsx:39:1 - error TS2322: Type '<T, U = T>(url:
> string, params: {} | undefined, axiosConfig: AxiosRequestConfig |
> undefined) => Promise<ApiErrorResponse |
> ApiOkResponse | { ...; }>' is not assignable to type '<T, U =
> T>(url: string, params?: {} | undefined, axiosConfig?:
> AxiosRequestConfig | undefined) => Promise<ApiResponse<T, U>>'.
> Type 'Promise<ApiErrorResponse | ApiOkResponse | { ok: true; data: never; }>' is not assignable to type
> 'Promise<ApiResponse<T, U>>'.
> Type 'ApiErrorResponse | ApiOkResponse | { ok: true; data: never; }' is not assignable to type 'ApiResponse<T,
> U>'.
> Type 'ApiErrorResponse' is not assignable to type 'ApiResponse<T, U>'.
> Type 'ApiErrorResponse' is not assignable to type 'ApiErrorResponse'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'U'.
> 'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.
>
> ```
> 39 apiClient.get = async (url, params, axiosConfig) => {
> ```

I have tried to add in more type hinting and return types.
However, I can't figure out how to return as the following type: `ApiResponse<T, U> | PromiseLike<ApiResponse<T, U>>`

```
const get = apiClient.get
apiClient.get = async <T, U = T>(
  url: string,
  params?: {},
  axiosConfig?: AxiosRequestConfig
): Promise<ApiResponse<T, U>> => {
  const response = await get(url, params, axiosConfig)

  if (response.ok) {
    cache.store(url, response.data)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(ApiOkResponse<response.data>)
    })
  }

  const data = await cache.get(url)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (data) {
      resolve({ ok: true, data })
    }

    reject(response)
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/Q)?

Comment: Here's the playground.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=99&module=1&inlineSources=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwMZQKYEMaoL5wGZQQhwDk6YwAzugK5KokDcAUM0hAHaXznADCAG2CoO8ALxwUGLAAoEzOHABG6SqgCqAJQAyALlIALGDDCVdAenNR0HACZEaaqADoQDADTNsAShZtO3HAA5qjicLyCwqLOITB+lgB64QJYUMAcQXAwBqjBoTLezBFCIjAxoXASqgCeHEhwMjRQAu5wYOjWIJSt6AAewBCUfJx4wEHelQB8iAqSAfBolJBcuVUA7ujA8LGNza3tnd3h-YPDHKPjfoqWcPbpmZREoQb3rIpoME0ccIvLal4sIA

Comment: I would just cast the return type: https://tsplay.dev/w2poYm

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was missing.
for reference, this is what I ended up with for the original issue and not simplified example.  https://tsplay.dev/mbK24W